# Waving his flag around the globe?

Tags: translation, synonyms

I'm onto translating an article about a chef who has several restaurant around the globe and the original sentence (*Turkish*) included an idiom like following to indicate the chef's omnipresence and popularity in the culinary scene:

> "Thus he's currently waving his flag around the globe."

or in a more direct translation:

> "He has his banners waving in every corner of the world."

Yet, I cannot translate the idiom directly and I don't have any alternative to use instead.

Can you help me find the closest translation?

Answer (score 1):

**The chef in question is making his presence known** by ... *waving his flag or his banners* [**promoting himself or advertising his products**] [**widely**] around the globe or in every corner of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could possibly maintain the flag/banner notion by changing "wave" to "plant" **(planting his flag)**:

> "He has planted his flag in every corner of the world"/
>
> "His flags/banners are [firmly] planted in every corner of the
>   world."/
>
> "Thus he's currently planting his flag/banner around the globe."

But for its unfortunate relation with urine, you could perhaps consider "**marking his territory**":

> "He has marked his territory in every corner of the world"/
>
> "His territory is [clearly] marked in every corner of the world."/
>
> "Thus he's currently marking his territory around the globe."

**Strutting his stuff** could work, but only if the chef is pompous/doing all this in a pompous fashion and you wish to point this out:

> "Thus he's strutting his stuff in every corner of the world/around the globe"